# C Integer Pointer Memory Address Suddenly Changes

Tags: c, memory-address

Say we have a file that has this content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
1
4
5
3
2
1
5
1
2
3
4
```

Then with this code:

```
int main(){

    FILE * file = fopen("CondorcetVote.txt", "r");

    int candidateCount = 4;
    int voters = 5;
    int voteClassificationSize = 5;

    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;
    int votePosition, voteIndex;
    char * temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    CommonVote * cV = malloc(sizeof(int) * voters);
    int groupCVCount = 0;

    int * votesToModify = calloc(voters * voteClassificationSize, sizeof(int));
    int add = 0;

    printf("VC %d\n", voteClassificationSize);

    for(a=0;a<voters;a++){
        (cV+a)->votes = calloc(voteClassificationSize, sizeof(int));
        for(b=0;b<voteClassificationSize;b++){
            *( ((cV+a)->votes) + b) = 0;
           // printf("%p\n", ( ((cV+a)->votes) + b));
            //printf("Initialize Dis %d\n", *( ((cV+a)->votes) + b));
        }
        (cV+a)->count = 0;
    }

    //for(a=0;a<v)


    for(a=0;a<voters;a++){
        for(b=0;b<voteClassificationSize;b++){
            fgets(temp, NAME_MAX, file);
            int length = strlen(temp);
            temp += length - 1;
            *temp = '\0';
            temp -= length - 1;
            *(votesToModify+add) = getIntegerFromChar(temp);


            ///printf("VTM: %d\n", *(votesToModify+add));
            add++;
        }
    }

    add = 0;

    for(a=0;a<voters;a++)
        for(b=0;b<voteClassificationSize;b++){
            printf("%d\n",*( ((cV+a)->votes) + b));
        }

  fclose(file);
  free(cV);
  free(temp);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that the address CHANGES. Even though the integer pointer votes has enough allocated size and the address is actually printed correctly if printed just after the calloc function is called, if the address is printed in the third loop as shown above, it will still print right, until the variable a in the second loop reaches 4, which the he memory address will change SUDDENLY.

this is the printed address:

```
00782C68
00782C6C
00782C70
00782C74
00782C78
007823C8
007823CC
007823D0
007823D4
007823D8
007823E8
007823EC
007823F0
007823F4
007823F8
00000001
00000005
00000009
0000000D
00000011
```

Looking at the last address, the value immediately changed into something...
Need help in this problem.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of CommonVote, and `CommonVote * cV = malloc(sizeof(int) * voters);` looks extremely suspicious.

Comment: Suggest `cV = malloc(sizeof(int) * voters);` --> `cV = malloc(sizeof *cV * voters);`

Comment: `fgets(temp, NAME_MAX, file);` --> `fgets(temp, 100, file);`

Comment: CommonVote is jsut a typedef that contains a single variable: integer pointer. @Monica, this made the code work. Thank you very much.